# How to color the cells in excel if "If..." condition is true

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to know how to color A1 of sheet 3 if sheet1!A1 = sheet2!A1. I would like to check the cells from A1 to A1000 of both sheet 1 & 2 and color the result in sheet 3.

Thanks.

Comment: This sounds like a perfect opportunity to use Excel's built-in conditional formatting... No VBA necessary! Check out a quick guide here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/quick-start-apply-conditional-formatting-HA010370614.aspx

Answer (score 0):

For versions earlier than Excel 2010, you need to use named ranges to refer to other sheets.

One option: Create a named range on Sheet2 that references cells A1 to A1000. Then use conditional formatting with this formula

```
=A1=INDEX(CompareRange,ROW(A1))
```

If you don't want to use a named range, you can use a helper column on Sheet1 with a formula

```
=A1=Sheet2!A1
```

Then base the conditional format on that column, where the results will be either TRUE or FALSE.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, the built-in conditional formatting does not let you format cells based on cells in other worksheets or workbooks. Therefore, the task at hand does require the use of VBA. An example of how a solution might look is attached below. You will need to replace the contents of formatAsDesired with the actual formatting you require.

```
Sub compareMyRanges()
'this sub executes the code below for your actual ranges in your actual project
    compareRange Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:A1000"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:A1000"), Sheets("Sheet3").Range("A1:A1000")
End Sub

Sub compareRange(inRangeOne As Range, inRangeTwo As Range, outRange As Range)

    For Each Row In outRange.Rows
        If inRangeOne.Cells(Row.Row, 1).Value = inRangeTwo.Cells(Row.Row, 1).Value Then
        'if there is a match between column 1 and column 2, formatAsDesired 
        'is called for the respective cell in column three   
        formatAsDesired outRange.Cells(Row.Row, 1)
        End If
    Next Row

End Sub

Sub formatAsDesired(formatRange As Range)
'formats Range with green fill. Replace the contents of this sub with whatever 
'formatting or transformation you require for the cells that match.
    With formatRange.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 5296274
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: In Excel 2010 you can base CF on another sheet in the same workbook. I think you could even in 2003. -1.

Comment: When trying to reference Sheet1!$A$1 in conditional formatting > format based on formula I get an error message saying something like 'you cannot use references to other tables or workbooks in conditional formatting'

Comment: You don't say what version. My previous comment was incorrect, I think, regarding Excel 2003, but you can definitely refer to other worksheets in CF in Excel 2010. What version are you using?

Comment: Sorry, just noticed. I'm using Excel 2007. Maybe you could supply the correct formula for conditional formatting then, since it's working on Excel 2010?

Comment: That explains that then :-)